# Freeze Cells in Excel Based on a Specific Cell that Changes

Tags: excel

I have tried to write a VPA that will allow me to freeze/block certain cells based on the content of a cell that is populated by a drop down box but i keep getting an error. Can someone have a look at this for me?

Thanks :)

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ActiveSheet.Cells("B6").Text = ("Convenience") Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(("B37"), ("B38"), ("B39"), ("B41"), ("B42"), ("B44"), ("B45"), ("B47"), ("B48")).Locked = True
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Range(("B37"), ("B38"), ("B39"), ("B41"), ("B42"), ("B44"), ("B45"), ("B47"), ("B48")).Locked = False
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect I know the answer to this but where which line of code throws the error? and what is the error message that you get?

Comment: Hi Zac, thanks for coming back to me! 
Im getting a run time error "5" Invalid procedure or argument. Its coming from the second line of my code.

Comment: Thought so. Remove the parentheses in your `IF` statement and change `Text` to `Value`. But the main issue is that if you want to reference the cell with an address, use `Range`.. so your statement should now look like: **If ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value = "Convenience" Then**. I would also recommend that you don't use `ActiveSheet`.. it's fraught with danger and can cause unforeseen issue. Try binding your sheets.. so if the sheet you are working with is in the same work book as your code, you could do: **If Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value = "Convenience" Then**

Comment: Thanks! With these changes im seeing a run time error 9 that's saying my subscript is out of range? Im sorry im completely new at this.

Comment: Mo worries. Is it on the same line of code? (i.e. the `IF` condition). If so, and if you are not using `ActiveSheet`, make sure you have the correct sheet name (i.e. in the example I gave I used `"Sheet1"`.. your sheet might be called something different)